# UiAutomator handle EditText Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, automation, android-uiautomator

I have to enter a password and to retype it. I retype it wrong and i get a EditText Error. 
Tried to catch this error in my uiautomator tests but the uiautomatorviever cant see the the error, it gives me all elements but not this error or any input error..

Is there a way to print that inputfield error? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3qNf.png)

Thanks